# Autolayout issue iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints, autolayout

Newbie question.

I added UIScrollView as subview to main view in Interface Builder and after that I added UILabel above UIScrollView. In landscape mode label scrolls fine (label's height more than scrollView height) but in portrait it can't be scrolled.I realize that I need to delete some scrollView autolayout constraints, but all of them have delete option in inactive state in Utilities -> Size Inspector. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure the content size of the UIScrollView is higher than the view size?

Comment: in -viewDidLoad i write [scrollView setContentSize:label.frame.size];

Comment: Do you know the exact value is? Try to print it, may be in landscape the label.size(contentSize) is larger than the screen size but not in portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said :

> "I added UILabel above UIScrollView"

That means `UILabel` is a `subView` of `UIScrollView`, right?
If you are using `autoLayout` then this is not an issue. Using `autoLayout` device decides frame of the `UIControls` itself thats why you are not able to scroll the `UILabel`

Get rid of `autoLayout` and you will be able to scroll the `UILabel` after setting `[scrollView setContentSize:aframe];`. And if due to some reason you can not leave `autoLayout` then you can override `autoLayout` after it loads using this `delegate` method

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{

...........Your code goes here

}
```